# natural log of an integral

Tags: integration, logarithms

So, this is probably a stupid question, but it has been a little bit since I took calculus, and have forgotten some of the specifics. I tried researching this, but for whatever reason I couldn't find anything. I'm pretty sure this is illegal, but if it isn't it turns this problem from nearly impossible to fairly easy, which I know is usually a sign that you are doing something wrong.

Here is what I tried to do

[image]

Thanks for any help, just a "yeah that's fine" or "no, you idiot" is sufficient!

Comment: Sorry, you can't. $log(\int)\neq \int(log)$.

Comment: [MSE MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't interchange the $\log$ function with integration. 
Observe
\begin{align}
\log\left(\int^\infty_0 e^{-x}\ dx \right) = \log\left(1\right) = 0
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \log e^{-x}\ dx=\int^\infty_0 -x\ dx = -\infty.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this problem is the integration of a complex gaussian.
you should multiply by the constant that will add exactly what you need in the exponent in order to et the form:
$$
e^{ - \frac{{(x - \mu i)^2}}{\sigma }} .
$$